# FT of a nonlinear term using FFTW3 and q = 0

Tags: c, fft, fftw, derivative, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to apply an integration algorithm for PDEs called [Exponential Time Differencing](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a47/a0c3f84a5aa1ef8016b8d9655951bc830933.pdf) using C language and the library FFTW3. Without going too much into details, I need to calculate the FT of a nonlinear term which is the derivative of a function squared:

[image]

The way I do it is the following:

1) Define lattice size

```
int Nx = 500;
double dx = 0.2;
```

2) Calculate wavevectors

```
for ( i = 0; i < Nx/2+1; i++ ) {
    qx[i] = 2.0*i*pi/(Nx*dx);
}
```

3) Execute FFTW3 plan to obtain FT of h from initial conditions (IC not shown in the code)

```
plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d (Nx,dh,dhft,FFTW_ESTIMATE);    //dh -> dhft
fftw_execute (plan_forward);
```

4) Calculate the FT of derivative of h

```
for ( i = 0; i < Nx/2+1; i++ ) {
// dxhft[i][0] are the real parts and dxhft[i][1] are the imaginary
dxhft[i][0] = -qx[i] * dhft[i][1];    // Re[FTdxh] = -q Im[FTh]
dxhft[i][1] = qx[i] * dhft[i][0];     // Im[FTdxh] = q Re[FTh]
}
```

5) Set the Nyquist element to 0 (as explained e.g. [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/65891-1.php))

```
dxhft[Nx/2][0] = 0.0;
dxhft[Nx/2][1] = 0.0;
```

6) Transform the derivative in real space using inverse Fourier Transform

```
plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d (Nx,dxhft,dxh,FFTW_ESTIMATE); //dxhft -> dxh
fftw_execute (plan_backward);
```

7) Normalise the derivative by Nx and calculate the nonlinear term

```
for ( i = 0; i < Nx; i++ ) {
    dxh[i] = dxh[i] / (double) (Nx);
    Nonl[i] = dxh[i]*dxh[i];
  }
```

8) Transform the nonlinear term

```
fftw_execute_dft_r2c (plan_forward,Nonl,Nonlft);    // Nonl -> Nonlft
```

Ok. Now, I have reasons to believe that the FT of the nonlinear term for q=0, that is the elements `Nonlft[0][0]` and `Nonlft[0][1]`, is wrong. But I don't understand what I am missing in the code. Can anyone give me some insight on the problem?

Comment: Hi! Is your signal periodic, featuring a period consistent with the frame ?  If it is not the case, the treatment is performed on the periodization of a frame on the signal. If repeating the frame creates a discontinuity, spectral leakage can be induced. The spurous frequencies will then be amplified by taking the derivative and squaring. If this issue arrises, could you try to apply a window, such as the Tukey window, prior to the treatment? In addition, could you test a sine function featuring a period consistent with the size of the frame?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @francis , but finally i discovered that the reason I had to believe that the FT of the nonlinear term for q=0 is wrong, was false! Everything makes sense. I leave the question just so it could be useful for someone doing derivatives with FFTW.